# Can I use generics to change a subclass' method signature?

Tags: c#, generics

I need to perform an operation on a subclass and return a result:

```
public interface IEntity { }

public abstract class Entity : IEntity {
  public abstract IEntity doStuff(IEntity e1, IEntity e2, IEntity e3);
}

public class Customer : Entity {
  public override IEntity doStuff(IEntity e1, IEntity e2, IEntity e3) {    // <-- yuck
  var customer1 = e1 as Customer;                                          // <-- yuck
  var customer2 = e2 as Customer;                                          // <-- yuck
  var customer3 = e3 as Customer;                                          // <-- yuck
  // do stuff
  return foo;
  }
}
```

I want to avoid that subclass' method signature, and the associated typecasting.

So I prefer this:

```
public override Customer doStuff(Customer c1, Customer c2, Customer c3) {
  // do stuff
  return foo;
  }
```

How would I use the type system to accomplish that?

EDIT: *I changed the name of the method from `compare` to `doStuff`, to reiterate that the operation itself is irrelevant. I'm not trying to compare. I just want to change the types. How do I do that?*

---

*Many have said to change the design, but that I cannot do. I already have a solution, which I've included below, and it works. If you have a better way to accomplish this, without criticising the design (which is not the point), then please let me know. Thanks for everyone's contribution though.*

Comment: I think an important part the question's missing is *why* you want/need to do it this way, rather than just `public Customer ChooseBetter(Customer c1, Customer c2)`, or a typical `IComparable<T>` or `IEquatable<T>` implementation. What do you want the caller to be able to do with these classes?

Comment: @31eee384 If I have an inheritence tree, I need to start with an interface or a generic. Also, like mentioned above, the operation itself isn't the core of the problem, it's how to change the signature that's confusing me.

Comment: What do you want to happen when `e1` or `e2` (or both? you probably only wanted one parameter, and use `this` for the other...) are *not* `Customer`s?

Comment: @31eee384 If they are not customers, I'd have some other reason for this. I don't want to bog down the question with more complexity (it has to do with reporting though).

Comment: To be blunt, the question as is looks like an XY problem. When I read it, the example you gave in no way points to generics as a possible solution. The naming isn't the issue--I just have no idea what you want in general. If you have a hierarchy, describe that hierarchy, and why you want to "change the types" (and what that means).

Comment: @31eee384 Thanks for trying to help. I'm simplified the question, which now is very simple: "how do I change the signature". Everything else is a diversion.

Comment: Don't put too much "meat" into the domain objects. For example, Active Record puts retrieve/store into the objects. In DDD you rely on repositories because you don't want to put irrelevant non-domain related "persistance code" into a domain object. KISS and SRP.

Comment: Good, that helps, but it still doesn't explain why you need anything other than `Foo Bar(Foo a, Foo b)`, and what you mean by "change the types". (Or, for that matter, why you see the two as connected.)

Comment: @31eee384 Because in the overridden method, I want to use the concrete types without typecasting. The solution I posted does that, and  makes my class easier to use by its consumers. Defensive coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. But the self-referencing generics make my head hurt.

```
public interface IEntity { }

public abstract class Entity<TEntity> : IEntity where TEntity : IEntity {
  public abstract TEntity doStuff(TEntity e1, TEntity e2, TEntity e3);
}

public class Customer : Entity<Customer> {
  public override Customer doStuff(Customer c1, Customer c2, Customer c3) {
    // do stuff
    return foo;
  }
}
```

Is this a good solution, or are there gotchas in there that'll give me problems?

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You're on the right track.  Check out the IEquatable<T> interface for a pretty standard way to implement this.

Comment: Like I mentioned above I just chose "compare" at random (maybe a poor choice). I don't really need to compare per se. I could also use `chooseBetterCustomer()`, `selectHighestProfitAccount()`, etc. etc. The real point I'm trying to make is to change the signature...

Comment: Okay, but those methods sound pretty specific to a type of entity, so how would you implement them on an abstract class and force their implementation?

Comment: @dustmouse Not terribly important, because the idea is to change the types. I chose the example at random. But to answer you, I suppose, there is `Entity` -> `Customer` -> `EnterpriseCustomer`, but there is also `Entity` -> `Product`, etc. So this problem might not be on the root base class `Entity`, but one of the intermediate ones like `Customer`.

Comment: In that case you shouldn't enforce the method on your root Entity but at whatever base class level makes sense.  And you wouldn't need to use generics.

Comment: @dustmouse Yes I'd need generics if the inheritence tree is deep enough. Which it is in my case.

Comment: To make your head hurt a bit more, you can require `where TEntity : Entity<TEntity>` at the abstract base class declaration which is a bit more specific than the `where TEntity : IEntity` you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

In the prospect of persistance ignorance, serialization (JSON/XML) and binarization for network transmission, you may be better off without the interface.

To distinguish from POCO classes which are also called entities I prefer the original term "Domain Object" as given in Eric Evans' original work.

This is just an example on what I would do.

```
public abstract class AbstractDomainObject<T>
  where T : AbstractDomainObject
{
    public abstract bool CanDoStuffWith(T other);
}

public class Customer : AbstractDomainObject<Customer>
{
    public override bool CanDoStuffWith(Customer other)
    {
        return this.Gender != other.Gender;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look closely you'll see that my answer isn't either. The capability of comparing is added through a generic interface, while the domain object stays abstract (and is not elevated to an interface itself). You can define more capabilities as generic interfaces and attach them to your inheritance tree where appropriate. This above is just an example for comparing objects which is easy to declinate into other scenarios.

Comment: Okay I see now. But just so that I understand you correctly, your solution differs from mine solely in that you've avoided the interface?

Comment: I've removed the `IComparable<T>`. And yes, I've just removed the interface `IEntity` because you don't need it (at least from your example/exposition, it may be necessary for other reasons). In the new example you can see how to compare or "do stuff" without interfaces and using just inheritance and generics. Use the most simple tools, avoid over-designing.

Comment: Okay I see. In my design the interface is regrettably necessary, but I like how your inheritence tree is designed. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is coming across as confusing is that this

```
public abstract class Entity : IEntity {
    public abstract IEntity doStuff(IEntity e1, IEntity e2, IEntity e3);
}
```

shouldn't implement `IEntity`. If you need a class that "does stuff" with an `IEntity` then that's separate from an `IEntity`. That's the Single Responsibility Principle. Unless the primary purpose of an `IEntity` is to `doStuff` then `doStuff` wouldn't be in the same class.

Whatever `doStuff` *does*, that's what this class should be. For example, if it compares whether instances of `IEntity` are compatible for some operation, you might do this:

```
public interface ICompatibilityChecker<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    bool AreCompatible(TEntity entity, TEntity other);
}
```

Then you might find that you don't even need an abstract class:

```
public class CompatibilityChecker : ICompatibilityChecker<Customer>
{
    public bool AreCompatible(Customer entity, Customer other)
    {
        //check compatibility
    }
}
```

Another principle involved is [Favor Composition Over Inheritance](https://codingdelight.com/2014/01/16/favor-composition-over-inheritance-part-1/). There's a tendency to want to put functionality into base classes when it often makes more sense to put it into entirely separate classes. But notice how when you separate out some of these behaviors into separate classes the design of those classes becomes much simpler.

Also, what if you have domain objects that don't need that behavior? Then the inheritance becomes more difficult because you might need other methods in the abstract class but you're stuck implementing another one that you don't even need.

More often than not when we try to share functionality between classes by having them inherit from common base classes it gets convoluted and eventually breaks down. It's much easier to maintain if we separate behaviors and responsibilities into separate classes.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide your thoughts. I agree with almost 100% of what you've said. In our case though, it's a design restriction. The entities are modeled after a DDD fashion, and responsible for their own operations. Your example is advocating a service class, which would solve one problem but create others in our design. All I wanted to know was how to "change" the signature, not redesign the system. My solution above works BTW, and though it looks complicated, the class' consumer is shielded from that complexity.

Comment: Also, the problem with StackOverflow is that you often have to dumb-down your real problem, which you can't post online. So if the example itself is bad, people criticise it instead of addressing the question. So maybe my example isn't the greatest! :-) Thanks again.